# show multiple instance of video tag with it's loaded buffer - map buffers from video tag to other video tags

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to show multiple instances of a video tag on one page. I'm trying to find a way to read video buffers and use MediaStream to append the buffers to another video tag. But it seems there is no such an api in video tag.

Is there any way to do this? please let me know if you know any solutions.

NOTE: I don't want to use canvas to put image data on it because of performance issues in safari.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I need to show multiple instances of a video tag on one page...
>
> But it seems there is no such an api in video tag."*

You can try using the [CaptureStream API (intro)](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/capture-stream/). You can also check options in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream).

**CaptureStream** should not care if your video input is a media file or some appended buffers.

Note: In these stream copies...

- `autoplay` is needed for auto-displaying pixels,
- `muted` avoids hearing multiple audios.

This code is tested as working in Chrome (Windows), so let's hope it works in Safari (Apple) too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video id="vid_01" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="myfile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video id="vid_02" width="320" height="240" muted autoplay>
</video>

<video id="vid_03" width="320" height="240" muted autoplay>
</video>

<script>

var streamCopy;
var vid1 = document.getElementById('vid_01');
var vid2 = document.getElementById('vid_02');
var vid3 = document.getElementById('vid_03');

//# check if video is ready to be copied...
vid1.addEventListener("loadeddata", copyVidStream );

function copyVidStream ()
{
    if (vid1.readyState >= 3 ) //if ready then copy stream
    {
      streamCopy = vid1.captureStream();
      vid2.srcObject = streamCopy;
      vid3.srcObject = streamCopy;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I found it but because it's not supported on safari I couldn't use it :(